# JQuery .animate() Menu Slides Back

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a piece of code which runs when the user clicks on a picture. Basically a menu is supposed to slide in from off screen using the .animate() function. You are supposed to click the same button again to make it go back. However, when I click it, the menu appears but then immediately slides back in. I know this seems like an easy problem but I'm a newbie. Any help?

```js
// JavaScript Document
$(document).ready(function(e) {
  var menuopen = false;

  $("#menupic").click(function(e) {
    if (menuopen == false) {
      $(".menu").animate({
        left: "0px"
      }, 200)
      menuopen = true;
    }
  });

  $("#menupic").click(function(e) {
    if (menuopen == true) {
      $(".menu").animate({
        left: "-400px"
      }, 200)
      menuopen = false
    }
  });
});
```

```css
@charset "utf-8";

/* CSS Document */

.header {
  width: 1280px;
  background-color: #C29832;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  height: 60px;
  z-index: 1000;
}
#logo1 {
  position: fixed;
  left: 70px;
  top: 0px;
}
#menupic {
  cursor: pointer;
  background-image: url('http://placehold.it/180x180/322F37/C29832.png&text=Menu');
  background-size: contain;
  height: 60px;
  width: 60px;
  z-index: 1001;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
}
#menupic:hover {
  background-image: url('http://placehold.it/180x180/322F37/C29832.png&text=Menu2');
}
.menu {
  font-family: CordiaUPC;
  height: 800px;
  width: 400px;
  background-color: #000;
  color: #FFF;
  position: fixed;
  top: 60px;
  font-size: 36px;
  opacity: 0.85;
  left: -400px;
}
.menu div p {
  padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  position: relative;
  left: 50px;
}
.menu div {
  position: relative;
  top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css" type="text/css" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="animation.js"></script>
    <title></title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="menu">
      <div>
        <p>Home</p>
        <hr />
      </div>
      <div>
        <p>About</p>
        <hr />
      </div>
      <div>
        <p>Posts</p>
        <hr />
      </div>
      <div>
        <p>Other</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="header">
      <div id="menupic"></div>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/180x180/322F37/C29832.png&text=Logo1" height="60" width="60" id="logo1" />
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are binding same event twice so it is triggered twice and your variable menuope is set to true in first call and then in second call it is validated as true

change to this code

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
  var menuopen = false;

  $("#menupic").click(function(e) {
    if (menuopen == false) {
      $(".menu").animate({
        left: "0px"
      }, 200)
      menuopen = true;
    }
    else if (menuopen == true) {
      $(".menu").animate({
        left: "-400px"
      }, 200)
      menuopen = false
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to check for flags like ***true/false*** in this case. Just use it this way:

```
$("#menupic").click(function(e) {
  $(".menu").animate({
    left: $(".menu").css('left') == '-400px' ? "0px" : "-400px"
  }, 200);
});
```

check the test case below:

```js
$("#menupic").click(function(e) {
  $(".menu").animate({
    left: $(".menu").css('left') == '-400px' ? "0px" : "-400px"
  }, 200);
});
```

```css
.menu{position:relative;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='menupic'>menupic</div>
<div class='menu'>menu</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to do everything in the same function?

```
$("#menupic").click(function(e) {
    if(menuopen==false){
        $(".menu").animate({left:"0px"},200)
    menuopen=true;        

    }else{
        $(".menu").animate({left:"-400px"},200)
    menuopen=false;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Think about what your doing here: `menuitem` is initially `false`. So the first `if` statement is executed. At the end of that `if` statement, `menuitem` gets changed to `true`. **THEN** we get to the second `if` statement (in the second `click` handler), where you check whether `menuitem` is `true`. But it is – we just set it! So that `if` statement runs too – the menu slides in, then out again.

Instead, you want to use `else` to only run one or the other. (I've also removed the `== true` and `== false` as they are totally unnecessary - Google for a better understanding of `boolean`s and `if`s):

```
$("#menupic").click(function(e) {
    if (menuopen) {
        // close the menu
        $(".menu").animate({
          left: "-400px"
        }, 200)
        menuopen = false;
    } else {
        // open the menu
        $(".menu").animate({
            left: "0px"
        }, 200)
        menuopen = true
    }
});
```